# How to make an Angular Material slider vertical using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I am trying to make the angular material directive to render vertically.  I have tried using **transform:rotate** in the CSS but the slider starts behaving and rendering differently.

```
md-slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);

      max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}
```

Here is the link to [my plunker (link)](http://plnkr.co/edit/67NyE3c4QSej2RfPYaRB?p=preview).  I am using CSS because AFAIK there is no official vertical slider component for angular material.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is a vertical slider :)
Just add the attribute `md-vertical` to your slider.

Comment: When was this added?  The last time I checked around Sept 2015 this was only on the feature request list and I remember devs were talking about how it may not be a top priority as a vertical slider has few use cases.

Comment: Yes it's added in latest version of material. Try to use version 1.1.0-rc4 for example from cdn https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-material/1.1.0-rc4 It works for me